# How to set up Rubymine to work with Rails on Vagrant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, rubymine

I'm using `precise64` box and installed Ruby `2.0.0p481` and Rails 4.1.1 on it. I managed to set up connection in Rubymine with VM and even launch ruby script. But I don't understand how to work with Ruby on Rails projects. I'm creating empty project, as I don't really understand how to create Rails project through remote SDK in Rubymine. So then I create rails projects on VM with Git shell and download it to my local machine through Rubymine. As I understand I'm supposed to add Rails config in `Run/Debug Configurations` section, but when I try to do so I get `Rails sever launcher wasn't found in project`.

Could someone help or share a link on a guide?

Comment: Your core issue seems to be _"I don't understand how to work with Ruby on Rails projects."_, right ? I suggest you learn Rails first, web has plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Nope, I've worked with Rails before. I'm new to Rubymine :)